# Unregister BroadCast onDestroy()

Tags: android, audio, broadcast

My Code:(For Headset Control and change Volume )

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    headSetConn=new HeadSetBCast();
    registerReceiver(headSetConn, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)); 
}
```

How to unregister it in `onDestroy()` or when application get closed.
I am facing UI Hang Problem when I am using:

```
getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(headSetConn);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: unregisterReceiver without getApplicationContext, show your code, hanging problem is not related to unregisterReceiver

Comment: Is it in activity or fragment ??

Comment: @ArkarAung it is activity.

Comment: Thanks @Ish ,You are right, without getApplicationContext it will work fine, but I check the concept twice, if you are registering your receiver with help of getApplicationContext (getApplicationContext.registerReceiver() )then you can use getApplicationContext even at time of  unregisterReceiver() and One more thing if you are used getApplicationContext to register a Receiver then it will  auto unregister when your app get destroy/kill at any point otherwise you have to unregister manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unregister your Broadcast before activity close you should do it like this:

If is an activity, of this way:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
 unregisterReceiver(headSetConn);
}
```

If is an Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
 getactivity().unregisterReceiver(headSetConn);
}
```

Hope it helps, 
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,for me same thing working fine with onStop() method.

Comment: But you should not use in onStop() method.

Comment: Shouldn't you 1st unregister and then call the super.destroy?